# Why use the instrumental "тем", not the accusative "то" in "Не за тем я ... , чтобы ..."?

Tags: падежи

> Не за **тем** я ... , чтобы ...

In this construction, "тем" is used as a kind of placeholder word for the clause "чтобы ...", correct?

The description in [Wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0#Russian) seems to suggest that the preposition "за" used in the sense of "**for** (the purpose of)" takes the accusative case, not the instrumental case.

So I wonder why you need to use the instrumental "**тем**" here instead of the accusative "**то**", when the intended meaning of "за" is clearly "for".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`За`** + Instumental (besides other uses) satisfies purpose and is used to convey meaning of getting something (overlooked in the Wiktionary article)

> Я ходил **за** хлеб**ом** - I went to buy some bread
>   Я два часа простоял в очереди **за** билет**ами** - I spent two hours in a line to get tickets
>   В очереди **за** билет**ами** я стоял `за пожилой женщиной` - In the line for tickets I was behind an old lady

`затем..., чтобы.../затем, чтобы...` answers the question `зачем?` and is a construction for adverbial adjunct of purpose

> **Не затем** я 10 лет учился, **чтобы** работать за гроши / Я 10 лет учился **не затем, чтобы** работать за гроши - I've spent 10
>   years studying not in order to work for peanuts / I didn't spend 10 years studying just to be working for peanuts

**`За`** + Accusative (besides other uses) satisfies reason (also overlooked in the Wiktionary article)

`за то..., что.../за то, что ...` answers the question `за что?` and is a construction for adverbial adjunct of reason

> **Не за то**, я тебя люблю, **что** ты красива, а за то, что умна / Я тебя люблю **не за то, что** ты красива, а за то, что умна - It's not your beauty which i love you for, but your intelligence / I love you not because you're beautiful, but because you're intelligent

Answer (score 2):

**Не затем, чтобы** (не за тем, чтобы) is a conjunction,colloquial or old-fashioned, meaning **not with the purpose of** (synonym of не для того, чтобы )

> Он рассказывал об этом не затем (не для того), чтобы вызвать в нас простое любопытство.
>
> Не затем величал я себя паладином,
>
> Не затем ведь и ты приходила ко мне,
>
> Чтобы только рыдать над потухшим камином,
>
> Чтобы только плясать при умершем огне!
> (Блок А.)

By the way,  if you mean a preposition plus a pronoun,
the preposition за can be used with the accusative and the instrumental as well. See the table.

с родительным падежом – без, вокруг, для, из, от, у, с;

с дательным падежом – к, благодаря, согласно, вопреки, наперекор, навстречу, по;

с винительным падежом – сквозь, про, несмотря, через, в, на, под, **за**;

с творительным падежом – над, перед, между, **за**, под, с;

с предложным падежом – о, при, в, на.

Formally, затем, чтобы should be written like this, for separate writing there's another conjunction **с тем, чтобы**, but in reality ruscorpora has lots of examples with a "не за тем, чтобы." Затем, чтобы (за тем, чтобы) means purpose, за то, что means reason.